# Range copy does not return value

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to copy data from a closed worbook to the active one.
For that the user chooses a column from which a distinct set of cells has to be copied into the other workbook.

I already tried to help myself with answers to other related questions but now my copy & paste does **not return values**. I tried referncing the workbook but then I get errors.
Maybe there is also a workaround by not taking the range to get the column, because in fact I only need the column.
Thanks for your answers.

```vba
Sub ImportDatafromcloseworkbook()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Dim Clmn As Integer


Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTitleId = "SAP Actuals"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        
        Clmn = xRng1.Column
        MsgBox Clmn
        Range(Cells(16, Clmn), Cells(21, Clmn)).Copy
        xRng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(16, Clmn), Cells(21, Clmn)).Copy` needs a workbook/worksheet reference?

Comment: Reading a workbook without opening it is even possible (with ADODB), however, in practice this code opens another workbook. The code asks the user to choose a target range, but this line  `Range(Cells(16, Clmn), Cells(21, Clmn)).Copy`restricts copying to rows 16 to 21 in the target regardless of actual size of the chosen range and saved in xRng1 . Evaluate what is the desired result for you to paste the data.